# How to load lots of data from a paged api in SwiftUI efficiently?

Tags: swift, swiftui, get, combine, avkit

I have been trying to load some data from a backend server and it comes in page size of 10 elements per page.

I am using combine and the issue is i am getting back videos and images from the server as well.

How do i load them properly? I have tried adding reloading functionality but it all just slows down the app massively. This is my code right now:

```
class ProductDataService: ObservableObject {

    @Published var count = 1
    @Published var countPage = 0
    
    @Published var allProducts: [ListedItem] = []

    var productSubscription: AnyCancellable?

    init() {
        getProducts()
    }
    func getProducts() {
          guard let url = URL(string: "myBackendURL-api/product/?page=\(count)") else{return}
        
        
        productSubscription = NetworkingManager.download(url: url)
            .decode(type: Product.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .sink(receiveCompletion: NetworkingManager.handleCompletion, receiveValue: { [weak self] returnedProducts in
                self?.allProducts = returnedProducts.results
                self?.countPage = returnedProducts.count
                self?.nextPageView = returnedProducts.next
                self?.productSubscription?.cancel()
            })
    }
}
```

i would add the code for networking manager below as well, it's nothing unsual tho

my backend returns a json like this:

```
"count": 33,
    "next": "http://backend/product/?page=2",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 79,
            "productName": "Mango",
            "producDescription": "Banana",
            "product_image1": "https:something.png",

        },
```

For now I tried using the next parameter in every call to replace with the url property of my function but couldn't do it properly.

Right now am using the count of the total products and then inside my home view model i use:

```
    private let dataService = ProductDataService()
    
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    @Published var allProducts: [ListedItem] = []
    @Published var tempArray: [ListedItem] = [] // listeditem is one product
    
    init() {
        addSubscribers()
    }
    
    func addSubscribers() {
        dataService.$allProducts
            .sink { [weak self] (returnedProducts) in
                self?.allProducts += returnedProducts    
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
```

And then i use a scrollview reader to read if the person reached the end of the screen to load more items.

I call this function from my view:

```
func loadMoreData() {
        if allProducts.count < dataService.countPage {
            if dataService.count < Int(dataService.countPage/10) {
                print("our comparing value is \(Int(dataService.countPage/10))")
                dataService.count += 1
                dataService.getProducts()
            }
            else {
                dataService.count -= 1

            }
           
            print("value of count is : \(dataService.count)")
            
        }
    else {
        print("our product count is more ")
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work exactly how i want it to be.

- First it just skips page 2 idk why and directly loads page 3 items. and now i have 33 items that is till page no. 4 but it never goes there due to my checks tho i can write +1 in my if conditon and it would work but still
- It also hangs the screen for 2 secs when loading.
- How do i show some progress view at that moment?
- Where do i but the boolean for that?
- Also is there a better way to load items from a GET Api rather than this?

Now I would add my image problem:

Now inside my product image view am dealing with videos and images like this:

```
var body: some View {
    if vm.image != nil {
        if let image = vm.image {
            Image(uiImage: image)

        }
        else if vm.isloading {
            ProgressView()
        }

    }
    else if let stringUrl = Optional(vm.product.product_image1) {
        ZStack {
            customVideoPlayer(player: player)
                .onAppear {
                    player.isMuted = isVideoMuted
                    if player.currentItem == nil {
                        let item = AVPlayerItem(url: URL(string: stringUrl) !)
                        player.replaceCurrentItem(with: item)

                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

The issue here is that before loading any image it takes in the frame of a video. And then it loads as an image but why so? I don't understand at all. I want it to either show a loading screen but not blank video screens.

Comment: This question is absolutely massive, and is hard to understand because of the sheer amount of words and code you used. Please try creating a minimal example... (For example, you don't need to include every piece of info in your json code, and you don't need to include stuff like `.padding` or `.cornerRadius`. Please edit the question :)

Comment: okok i will try to change it @Stoic !

Comment: please see now if it makes sense, basically how do i do pagination efficiently

Comment: Please boil this down to a single question. As it is writen now there are about 6 or 7 different questions here. Try to solve one problem after another.